# How do I check if this grammar is LL(1), LR(0) and SLR(1)

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar

I have been studying the methods of all of these parsers and got confused among the parsers.
Can anyone show how would those parsers be checked on a single grammar?

Grammar:

```
S->Aa|bAa|dc|bda
A->d
```

Comment: Build the parsing automaton for the grammar according to the algorithm for each parser type. If there are no conflicts, then the grammar conforms to that type.

Comment: The grammar is ambiguous ('S' derives 'bda' in 2 different ways), so it can't be in any of those classes. So if you build the parsing automata (as indicated by @rici), you'll find that, in each one, the state accessed by "bd" has a shift-reduce conflict that can't be resolved by lookahead.